# Using EMA with a zoo object (matrix). Does EMA only work with vectors?

Tags: r, matrix, zoo

I have a zoo object (matrix), MyData, that looks like this.

AAPL.Adjusted SHY.Adjusted
2013-05-01         60.31        84.12
2013-05-02         61.16        84.11
2013-05-03         61.77        84.08
2013-05-06         63.25        84.08
  ....              ....        .....

When I try to do something like:

```
EMA(myData, n = 5)
```

I get a vector result of the first column only. I know how to pull myData apart into vectors, run EMA on each, and put it back together into a zoo matrix, but this seems arcane. What syntax do I use to make the EMA filter run on all columns of my data matrix, myData? Thanks for any help. I’m sure it is obvious but ... ??

Comment: `myData[] <- apply(myData, 2, EMA, n = 5)`

Comment: Thank you. I’m a newbie and was not familiar with the “apply” method. Works perfectly now.